# Handling exceptions in wrapper class converting methods from APM to TAP

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, task-parallel-library

I have a scenario where I want to create a wrapper class around a class exposing asynchronous methods using the APM pattern. My idea is that the wrapper class should take advantage of TAP pattern and expose wrapper methods such as exampled below:

```
public class ClassToBeWrapped
{
  ...
  // Throws ExceptionToBeWrapped when used incorrectly
  public void BeginRead()
  ...
}

public class WrapperClass
{
  ...
  public Task<int> ReadAsync()
  {
     return Task.Factory.FromAsync(classToBeWrapped.BeginRead,...);
  }
}
```

When the consumer of the wrapper class calls the ReadAsync method, I want any custom exception of the wrapped method to be wrapped and passed along to the consumer instead of the original exception.

```
public class ConsumerClass
{
  ...
  try
  {
    await wrappedClass.ReadAsync(...);
  }catch (WrappedException we)
  {
    // Does not catch WrappedException, only ExceptionToBeWrapped
    ...
  }
```

However, I always end up catching the non wrapped exception in catch method. I suspect I have to do some handling of this in the ReadAsync method but have failed so far.

Do any of you have any advise on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you saying that `catch (WrappedException we)` does not catch `WrappedException`. Can you post a reproducible example of that? Also, this starting guide may be helpful: [TAP Wrappers for APM Implementations](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/async-interop-with-iasyncresult.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just `await` the inner task, catch the exception, and throw the wrapped exception:

```
public async Task<int> ReadAsync()
{
  try
  {
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(classToBeWrapped.BeginRead,...);
  }
  catch (ExceptionToBeWrapped ex)
  {
    throw new WrappedException(ex);
  }
}
```